# Elle chante juste

Tags: sens

Je n'ai pas de contexte pour cette phrase. 
J'ai entendu dire

> Elle chante juste

Qu'est-ce que cela veut dire exactement ? Qu'elle chante sans faute ou qu'elle chante avec un tempérament équitable ?

Comment: Chanter juste c'est savoir reproduire de façon exacte, immédiatement ou en différé, une mélodie ou une note. [Définition par un professeur de chant](https://chantattitudevoix.com/que-signifie-chanter-juste/). Mais pour plus de technique ce n'est pas une question de français, c'est une question de musique et ce n'est pas ici qu'il faut poser la question. [Music StackExchange](https://music.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: « Chanter avec un tempérament *équitable* ?  » —  Il faut avoir du *tempérament* pour chanter en public et le captiver, mais *équitable* (qui est une notion de droit, de Justice et non de justesse) n’a aucun sens ici, quel sens donnez-vous à ce mot ?

Comment: @cl-r, _tempérament_ a un sens technique en musique, je suppose que c'est celui désiré ici (il désigne, d’après ce que je comprends, la manière d'accorder les notes de la gamme, ce qui le rend pertinent dans ce contexte). _équitable_ par contre me semble mal choisi (mais je ne suis pas musicien, je me trompe peut-être).

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=temp%C3%A9rament+%C3%A9quitable+musique&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url= *KO* — https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=temp%C3%A9rament+%C3%A9quitable&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctemp%C3%A9rament%20%C3%A9quitable%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctemp%C3%A9rament%20%C3%A9quitable%3B%2Cc0 *Notions de droit* — Je ne l’ai trouvé que dans un seul article concernant la musique https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-00686843/document … à ne pas utiliser hors de ce contexte

Answer (score 5):

***[Juste](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/juste)*** est ici un adverbe qui s'oppose à *faux*. Son rôle est de modifier ou préciser le sens de *chanter*.

« Chanter juste », c'est chanter de façon harmonieuse, en respectant les notes attendues. Le sens est donc proche de la première proposition : chanter sans faute, mais concerne uniquement la musique. On peut se tromper dans les paroles d'une chanson et néanmoins chanter juste.

On retrouve les adverbes *juste* et *faux* avec le verbe *sonner*. Par exemple un instrument correctement accordé *sonnera juste* et dans la négative, *sonnera faux*.

D'autre part, comme déjà commenté, l'expression *tempérament équitable* n'a pas de sens dans ce contexte. Je soupçonne qu'elle résulte d'une traduction hasardeuse par Google translate ou similaire. Il faudrait connaître l'expression originale et sa langue pour comprendre ce qui était attendu.

Comment: C'est juste. Enfin c'est pas faux.

Comment: @Destal C'est vrai. Enfin c'est pas faux.

Answer (score 0):

Elle change dans la gamme c'est a dire qu'elle chante dans la 'note' exemple : elle chante dans la gamme de mi, ou fa